# What is this silver component?

Tags: components, identification

Anyone know what this silver component is? Tried to google it, but no luck.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That component is a surface mounted polyfuse. A resettable fuse that trips at elevated temperature and resets as it cools down.

These components are made in many package styles in addition to the one you show.

[image]

<sup>Picture Source: [Littelfuse.com](http://www.littelfuse.com/products/resettable-ptcs.aspx).</sup>

Answer (score 23):

It is a resettable (poly) fuse, [similar to this product](http://www.futureelectronics.com/en/technologies/electromechanical/circuit-protection/resettable-fuse/Pages/1114651-SMD030F-2.aspx?IM=0)

[image]

Comment: Probably a Bourns MF-SM250, a 2.5A polyfuse. See [datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/mfsm.pdf?sfvrsn=a413899b_25)